# Why are row numbers 10 and 11 skipped on Frontier's A-319?

Tags: airbus-a320

I'm sitting behind an exit row (the exit row is row 12), but am still not sure why rows 10-11 are missing from this plane. Note the number goes from 9 to 12.

[image: Row numbers skip from 9 to 12]

Why are the rows numbered this way? It's the same on both sides.

Comment: Also notice how you're in row 14, right behind 12?

Comment: No, I'm in row 13. All the other rows are sequential.

Comment: Interesting. I've never seen a row 13 on an airliner (I suppose many buildings have [no 13th floor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirteenth_floor) for the same reason)

Comment: A random check of seat plans reveals row 13 appears often enough, right there between 12 and 14.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Airline row numbering has more to do with fleet consistency than sequential numbering in one airplane type.

Head over to [SeatGuru](http://seatguru.com) and look up *Frontier*. They fly 3 types of mid-size narrowbody - A319, A320, Embraer E190 - and not surprisingly row 12 is an exit row in each one. The E190 and A319 don't have row 11, only the A319 is missing row 10.

It's the same reason 2+2 seating skips seats B and E ( AC DF ), where 3+3 seating goes all the way across ( ABC DEF ). Widebody aircraft have a different sequence because it doesn't need to match - the same cabin crew will rarely work both major classes and they don't tend to run regional airlines on widebody (long-haul) routes.

Look at Air Canada's fleet - row 18 is the beginning of economy and an exit row in almost the entire widebody fleet (the exception is probably historical).

Comment: Just to add some context, this is often done for the benefit of staff and frequent flyers, both of whom know without checking that row 12 is the exit row with the nice extra leg room - and can deliberately choose that row or avoid placing children etc in that row (as the passenger needs to be able to operate the exit)

Comment: @JonStory Additionally, if there is an equipment change, this scheme means you'll usually end up with the same type of seat.